# Save number with TTL (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ttl

I see a lot of TTL NodeJS packages using keys, however I can't use keys. I'd like to do something like this:

```
const responseTimes = []

// TODO: Implement a function to delete item in array at end of TTL

// function that runs
doSomething().then(response => {
  responseTimes.push({ duration: response.duration, TTL: thirtySeconds })
})

// function that gets 30s average
const getAverage = () => {
  return Math.AVG(responseTimes.map(time => time.duration))
}
```

**TTL** In this context means the `responseTime` object will be deleted after the TTL of 30 seconds in this case.

How would I accomplish the TODO of deleting array objects at the end of the specified `TTL` ?

Comment: The term "Time to Live (TTL)" is used in a lot of contexts. Are you wanting to set the TTL for a browser cache header?

Comment: @Cully great question, I only want the duration value to be saved for 30 seconds

Comment: What I'm asking is, what is the context? Are you talking about an HTTP cache TTL, redis key TTL, IP packet TTL, DNS TTL, etc?

Comment: Oh, I just want to be able to, at any moment, get the average responseTime for the last 30 seconds. I am trying to make a TTL for node

Comment: So, you want to implement some kind of cache that only hjolds objects for 30 seconds and delets them afterwards? In that case, what should getAverage return if called later than 30 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is not to implement any kind of cache with TTL, but instead, save a timestamp along with the responseTime. Then, when calling getAverage, ignore (or even delete) all response times who's timestamp is more than 30 seconds ago.

```
const responseTimes = []

// function that runs
doSomething().then(response => {
    responseTimes.push({ duration: response.duration, time: Date.now() })
})

// function that gets 30s average
const getAverage = () => {
    return Math.AVG(responseTimes
        .filter(entry => entry.time < (Date.now() - 30000))
        .map(time => time.duration)
    );
}
```

(This code only ignores and does not delete response times that are older than 30 secs - if you, over time, save many response times, then DO implement code that deletes old ones, otherwise memory will run full over time and the call to getAverage will take quite long ;-) )

Comment: How often would you recommend implementing the deletion logic? like every 1 second I presume?

Comment: That depends on how often you record new response times. You could add a counter you increase any time you add a new response time, and if it reaches a threshold, run deletion code within the same function that adds the new time.

Comment: @KevinDanikowski Also, I would advice against having a background task that runs deletion every x second - it's pointless, you don't need to do any deletions if you haven't inserted anything. It makes sense to pair cleanup with insertion.